# What is the proper way to set up Express routing with HTML files when using the ng-boilerplate kickstarter?

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm struggling to perform routing using Express in the ng-boilerplate structure.

I'd like to do it using HTML view files (as opposed to JADE).

Can anyone help provide examples of how to do this?

I keep getting `Failed to lookup view xx` errors when using `app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');
});`

Comment: Can you show what is configurations for your express app? And which view engine are you using?

Comment: I'm trying not to use a view engine and just use HTML files... is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your views directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() { 
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');  // <=== Where your HTML view files are present
        app.set('view engine', 'jade'); //Your view engine to be set here
    });
```

For detailed information:

- [Express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure)
- [Related Questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216395/error-failed-to-lookup-view-in-express)

Comment: This isn't quite what I wanted, since the code you gave uses jade as a view engine, but I got something working with ejs doing something similar to what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @manihiki Actually I commented in my answer like `//Your view engine to be set here` so you can use any template engines. Nice to see my answer help you yo solve issue in some way.. Happy coding & exploring..  :)