# Got a internal server error after I deploy my node js project to the host

Tags: node.js, heroku, kraken.js

I just finished my project and everything seems OK if I run it on localhost. But after I deploy the project on Heroku, the build process is ok, when I try to access the website, I got an `Internal Server Error`, I have no idea what the log is going to tell me (I'll paste the log below).

```
VError: Failed to lookup view "index.js" in directory "/app/.build/templates"

at /app/node_modules/makara/node_modules/engine-munger/index.js:99:33
at iterate (/app/node_modules/makara/node_modules/engine-munger/node_modules/permutron/index.js:91:20)
at iterate (/app/node_modules/makara/node_modules/engine-munger/node_modules/permutron/index.js:91:20)
```

Anybody knows why? Thanks!

Comment: Why it wants to find index.js in the templates folder

Comment: refer this post [Error: Failed to lookup view in Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216395/error-failed-to-lookup-view-in-express)

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, the link above might be talking about missing a view. But my app works just fine on my laptop, and I have never met that error before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one likely thing you can check for:

A Kraken app expects all resources (compiled dust templates, compiled LESS files, etc) to be present in the `.build` directory.

However, when a resource is not found there, the app's behavior is environment specific, based on the current `NODE_ENV` environment variable.

If not specified, by default, Kraken apps work in `development` mode.
When a resource is not found in `.build`, the app will try to generate it on the fly.

This is done as a convenience for developers, and it means you don't have to build the app every time you make a change, as resources will be compiled and loaded on the fly when you run your server.  (eg: If you make a change to a template, and reload that page, your change will show up immediately. no need to build)

This is less efficient, so typically you'll want to pre-compile all resources (dust templates, LESS files, etc) before deployment.

Heroku, by default is a **PRODUCTION** environment (See [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#runtime-behavior)), and they set `NODE_ENV` to `production`.

When deployed in `production` mode, your app expects all resources to be available in the `.build` directory. If a resource is not found, it will give up.

**Solution**
Build your app before deployment, by running `grunt build` (See [Documentation](http://krakenjs.com/#grunt-tasks))
Make sure that the `.build` directory is deployed to Heroku as well.