# React app failing on windows but works fine on Mac

Tags: reactjs, express

I see following error while running my application in Windows OS but my team members are able to run the app without any issues on Mac OS

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "dist".

My react and express version.

> "express": "^4.17.1",

> "express-session": "^1.17.1",

> "react": "^16.13.1",

> "react-dom": "^16.13.1",

I'm using windows 10, node v14.17.5, npm 6.14.14 and I don't have any clue to debug what's causing this issue.

[image: updated image]

Let me know I need to provide any additional details.

Comment: there are two backslashes in the fourth line before src like "\\src". Maybe there's an issue? Also in th the third line between "front-end" and "node_modules"

Comment: thats not the issue updated the image

Comment: could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216395/error-failed-to-lookup-view-in-express

Comment: doesn't widows use forward-slash`/` instead of back-slash`\\`

Comment: Did you build after pulling?

Comment: npm start command was "rimraf dist  && npm run start:dev && npm run build:dev" by changing the sequence to build first and then start it worked for me in windows OS, idk how this is working in Mac OS with start first and build later